# How to update value Reference child record found in oracle

Tags: database, oracle

I Want update data someone table  But  that table  Reference some one child record found i'm looking for some site 6 Hour but i can't find Solution And never child record Don't delete it.

Comment: We don't know your table structures, your data or your requirements. Please update your question to include your table DDLs, insert statements, expected output and the logic behind how to achieve the output based on the input. We don't need your exact table names and data; just enough sample data so we can run the statements for ourselves. Please test your DDL and insert statements to make sure they run ok. (You could even prepare a script in [LiveSQL](http://livesql.oracle.com) that you can share with us!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the changes you make on the parent table to cascade on to the child table(s) then you must explicitly tell the foreign key on the child table to `CASCADE` on `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  column1 datatype null/not null,
  column2 datatype null/not null,
  ...

  CONSTRAINT fk_column
     FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
     REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n)
     ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: It wasn't the answer I wanted, but I think it will help later.

Answer (score 2):

```
create table test1(
group_name varchar(20) primary key
);

create table test2(
seq number primary key,
group_name references test1(group_name)
);

commit;


insert into test1 values('test');

commit;


 select * from test1;


 insert into test2 values(1,'test');

 select * from test2;

 create trigger update_cascade
 after update of group_name on test1
 for each row
 BEGIN
    update test2 
    set group_name=:new.group_name
    where group_name=:old.group_name;
 END;
 /

 commit;

  select * from test2;

  update test1 set group_name='best' where group_name='test';

  select * from test1;

  select * from test2;
```

if will stop

```
ALTER TRIGGER MEETNOW.update_cascade disable;
drop trigger update_cascade;
commit;
```

I hope Some one beginners like me will help.

Comment: FWIW, if your primary key column(s) can be updated to different values, it's better to have a surrogate primary key using a sequence plus a unique constraint on the ex-primary key column(s). That way, should the name change, you don't need to update the child tables.